# Access static methods from default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
class Cat extend AppModel{
   public static function getCat($medium=NULL){
       $allcat = $this->Cat->find('all', array('contain' =>false,
                'conditions' => array('Cat.c_medium' => $medium), 
                 'order' => array('Cat.c_name' => 'asc')));
       return $allcat;
   }
}
```

I want to access this method from default.ctp like `Cat::getCat('eng');`
but this is not working, Please help me.

Error :- `Fatal error: Class 'Cat' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 100`

Answer (score 5):

You need to App::uses() the classes you want to use in your files.
For the view it is usually better to do this in the controller at the very top:

```
 <?php
     App::uses('Cat', 'Model');
```

Now the Cat model can be accessed in all controller actions and their views - especially via static access (for non-static access ClassRegistry::init() usually takes care of the including itself).

But in your case you are abusing static methods here.
You should only access models statically for non-query-methods.

This method here should have never been static in the first place.
Use the controller to call this method and pass the results down to the view.

Comment: There's an error in your example; 'Car' should be 'Cat' according to the question

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code;

1. `class Cat extend AppModel` should be `class Cat extendS AppModel` (not the extra 's' in extends)
2. Using `$this` in a static method is NOT possible. Static methods do not have an 'instance' of the class to refer to so `$this` will produce errors
3. You're using `$this->Cat->find(...)` *inside* the `Cat` model, itself, it should simply be `$this->find(...)`

Normally, you don't access Models inside your Views or Layouts. Models are used within your Controller and results passed to the view by providing them as 'viewVars';

// Your controller

```
class MyController extends AppController {
    // Specify the Models you want to use
    public $uses = array('Cat');


    public function my_action()
    {
       $this->set('my_view_var_name', $this->Cat->getCat('eng'));
    }
}
```

// The view (app/View/My/my_action.ctp):

```
debug($my_view_var_name);
```

**Via ClassRegistry::init()**

If you *want* it's possible to get an instance of a Model *anywhere*, also inside a View/Layout;

```
ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```

// Inside app/View/Layout/default.ctp

```
$cats = ClassRegistry::init('Cat')->getCat('eng');
debug($cats);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code -

Try this

```
<?php
  $cats = ClassRegistry::init('Cat')->getCat('eng');
  pr($cats);
?>
```